# Fastest hash of booleans and integers?

Tags: javascript, hash, hashmap

My high level goal is to be able to compare specific objects (which have the same type) by value rather than by reference. Every value in the object is either a boolean or a number, and speed is crucial.

Breaking this down a bit, I'm looking for a very fast function that goes from this object, into string or number (i.e. a hash), so that I can look up comparisons in a hash table.

I'm happy inlining all the calls for speed gains - it does not need to be automatic and there is no need for checking any `typeof`

For example:

```
const foo = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: 42
  }
  d: 3
}
```

Can be reduced down to [1,42,3], and then that could be used as a lookup key for the object, but converting this array to a string as a hash key won't work because there's no way of differentiating that from [1,4,23]

I've tried the suggestions at [hash algorithm for variable size boolean array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398578/hash-algorithm-for-variable-size-boolean-array) and that works great when my object can fit into a 32-bit TypedNumberArray - but once I need several of those arrays and calling `toString()` on them, it becomes slow (still much faster than JSON.stringify, however)

The target language is javascript though I'm happy to see code samples in C or other languages if it helps.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want reversibility, then you don't want a hash.

Comment: The other name for a hash function is a one way trapdoor. You only get to go one way.

Comment: Whups - the line "as well as the reverse" was an accident... removed it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
class Lookup {
  constructor() {
    this.lookup = {}
  }

  insert(value) {
    if (!(value.a in this.lookup))
      this.lookup[value.a] = {}
    if (!(value.b.c in this.lookup[value.a]))
      this.lookup[value.a][value.b.c] = {}
    this.lookup[value.a][value.b.c][value.d] = value
  }
}

const l = new Lookup()
const foo = {
  a: true,
  b: {
    c: 42
  },
  d: 3
}
l.insert(foo)
console.log('l.lookup[true][42][3] =', l.lookup[true][42][3])
```

The output is:

```
l.lookup[true][42][3] = { a: true, b: { c: 42 }, d: 3 }
```

Comment: doing it that way is definitely another option, thanks!

Comment: The 32-bit integer chunk thing was faster - though this was cleaner looking :)

Answer (score 0):

Whups, silly mistake! as @joseph-silber pointed out, the commas are included in Array.toString() so that's a non issue.

Still - curious to see other solutions to this problem :)

Comment: Worth pointing out though - Array.toString() is significantly slower than number.toString so the 32-bit array hash thing is the fastest performer in my local rough tests

Answer (score -1):

If you set the lookup key to the actual values

```
var lookup = [true,42,3]
```

you can use it as a hash value:

```
var values = {}
values[lookup] = foo
```

Comment: that does not turn it into a hash value, it looks up the array by reference